# Can we train a same network two times with Mathematica?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a simple question about Mathematica 11.3. Is is possible to train a model of neural network with NetTrain in several steps like with Keras?

Perhaps do I have to (1) create my model, (2) train it, (3) create a new model like in (1), copy the weights from (2) to (3), reuse NetTrain ?

It seems that once a first training is done, all the weights and bias are fixed with Mathematica.

Thanks for your help,
N.

Comment: I am 90% certain it is possible to copy the weights from one net to another. Look up the "Net Surgery" tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/neural-network-framework/perform-net-surgery-for-transfer-learning.html).

Comment: Look at (TrainingProgressCheckpoint)[https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrainingProgressCheckpointing.html]. This is certainly possible